# SQL Help (Join, transpose?)

Tags: sql

Please refer to the attached image. I have 3 tables - Region, Month, and Customer. I want to get a table like the Result table. How to achieve that? Not a sql expert. Any help is appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Post your schema in the question, not an image of the schema.  Some of us are behind firewalls and can't see your pictures.

Comment: Where are your columns North, South, East, and West??

Comment: @ryekayo - It's linked to a regionid.

Comment: @MikeS i know it's linked to regionid but im failing to figure out why Alex W is using 0s and 1s for representation and what these values are supposed to mean in his tables..

Comment: It's a count of customers in a region for a certain month.

Comment: There's actually supposed to be a two count for March in the South.

Comment: sorry your are right. there are a 2 count for March in the South.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditional aggregation:

```
select m.month,
       sum(case when c.regionid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as north,
       sum(case when c.regionid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as south,
       sum(case when c.regionid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as east,
       sum(case when c.regionid = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as west
from region r
cross join month m
left join customer c on c.regionid = r.regionid and c.monthid = m.monthid
group by m.monthid, m.month
```

Comment: You should add order by m.monthid asc so you get Jan - Dec.  But it looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there a way to dynamically get a list of regions from the Region table instead of hard coding the region Ids in the conditional statement?

Comment: Umfortunately no. If you are uaing SQL Server you can do some dynamic query, but I am not sure with other rdbmses.

Comment: I am looking at pivot/unpivot. Are they capable of doing this?

Comment: Which rdbms you use? In sql server you can do this with pivot but you will still have to hardcode regions unless you do dynamic query.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to do it using PIVOT (in SQL Server).  Just saw that you are using PostgreSQL which I believe doesn't have PIVOT but you can use CROSSTAB.  Here are some examples of that:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html
https://gist.github.com/romansklenar/8086496

rextester link for the code below:  http://rextester.com/VRZ32719

```
WITH REGION(regionid,  region)
    AS (select 1, 'North' union all
        select 2, 'South' union all
        select 3, 'East'  union all
        select 4, 'West' 
       )
,
CUSTOMER(customerid, regionid, monthid)
AS (select 1,1,1  union all
    select 2,1,12 union all
    select 3,2,3  union all
    select 4,3,4  union all
    select 5,4,3  union all
    select 6,4,10 union all
    select 7,2,2  union all
    select 7,2,2  union all
    select 8,3,1  union all
    select 9,2,3
   )
,
MONTH(monthid, month)
AS (select 1,  'Jan' union all
    select 2,  'Feb' union all
    select 3,  'Mar' union all
    select 4,  'Apr' union all
    select 5,  'May' union all
    select 6,  'Jun' union all
    select 7,  'Jul' union all
    select 8,  'Aug' union all
    select 9,  'Sep' union all
    select 10, 'Oct' union all
    select 11, 'Nov' union all
    select 12, 'Dec'
   )

select MONTH as ' ', NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST from
   (select m.month, r.region, c.customerid
    FROM CUSTOMER c
     JOIN REGION r
      ON c.regionid = r.regionid
    FULL OUTER JOIN MONTH m
      ON c.monthid = m.monthid
    ) as a
   pivot
   ( count([customerid])
     for [region] in ([NORTH],[SOUTH],[EAST],[WEST])
    ) pivot_table
;
```